# Error en conexion base de datos con phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Tengo este "error", estoy haciendo un proyectito y me pasaron este codigo y la base de datos(ya esta en phpmyadmin) y el cuerpo dle mismo en Netbeans, todo lo tengo como deberia estar, pero me sigue apareciendo :,c

> Error de Base De Datos: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) Linea de Error: 7 Notice:
>   Undefined variable: cnx in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\LibroSoft\Modelo\Conectar.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\LibroSoft\Modelo\Modelo_libros.php:13 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\LibroSoft\Controlador\controlador_libros.php(25): Modelo_libros->listar_libros() #1
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\LibroSoft\Controlador\controlador_libros.php(10):
>   listar_libros() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\LibroSoft\Modelo\Modelo_libros.php on line 13

```
class Conectar { 
   public static function conexion(){ 
      try{ 
         $cnx=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crisol','root',''); 
         $cnx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
         $cnx->exec('SET CHARACTER SET UTF8'); 
      } catch (PDOException $ex) { 
         echo 'Error de Base De Datos: '.$ex->getMessage()."<br>";
         echo 'Linea de Error: '.$ex->getLine(); 
      } 
   return $cnx; 
}
```

Comment: por favor lee [ask], evita colocar contenido extra que no tiene relación en el título de tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias por el aviso

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver con phpmyadmin?

Comment: la base de dats ha sido creado directamente en phpmyadmin

Comment: Y el código fuente?

Comment: el código indica un problema con tus credenciales de acceso. las cuales colocas en tu cadena de conexión; veo que no usas ninguna contraseña en tu conexión PDO; seguro que no ocupas ninguna?. Además de eso quité la etiqueta `netbeans` no hay necesidad de mencionarla pues aquí no juega ningún papel

Comment: Gracias, hasta donde se yo, no hay ninguna contraseña , si es posible como veo la contraseña, en caso tuviera una